# How to avoid the error: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

My goal is to generate a model that segment text into sentences.
I have a dataset (xlsx) with 24 columns: the first column is for instances (words), 22 features and the last column contains the class. Only the first column is a string, all the rest are integers.

My code:

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('File_xlsx', header=0, dtype=str)
testdataset = pd.read_excel('file_xlsx', header=0, dtype=str)

# Split-out validation dataset
array = dataset.values
testarray = dataset.values
X_train = array[1:-1]
Y_train = array[:,22]

X_test = testarray[1:-1]
Y_test = testarray[:,22]

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')
svclassifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#Predict values using the SVM algorithm model
Y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)

#Evaluation
Print(confusion_matrix(Y_test,Y_pred))
print(classification_report(Y_test,Y_pred))
```

After run, I get

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Alkl'

`'Alkl'` is the last line in the first column

My dataset 
print(dataset[:5])

```
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
0   dstwr  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
1    twns  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  2
2  Aljdyd  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
3     kml  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
4    nhAr  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

print(X_train[:5])

```
[5 rows x 24 columns]
[['twns' '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
  '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '2']
 ['Aljdyd' '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
  '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '2']
 ['kml' '1' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
  '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '2']
 ['nhAr' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
  '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '2']
 ['27' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
  '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '2']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines

```
X_train = array[:,0:22]
Y_train = array[:,22]

X_test = testarray[:,0:22]
Y_test = testarray[:,22]
```

are starting at the first column- try using this as your slice

```
[:,1:-1]
```

This will exclude the first and last columns and only grab the columns in between. I don't have your data set so I can't test if this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! when I try this solution, I get a 100% result. So there is a problem.
I'm using `X_train = array[:,1:-1]` and `Y_train = array[:,22]`. Does this mean that, for X_train, I only take the 2nd column with step -1?

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay close enough attention- if Y_train/test is supposed to be the last column then keep it there- my comment was more focusing on that you were starting your slice at the wrong column. Slicing follows the following format: [start:stop:step(opt.)]. If you do just [1:-1] it means start at index 1 (i.e. the second element) and stop before index -1 (i.e. the "last" element- python allows you to index from the last element of a collection using negative indices). If you did something like [1:-1:2] it would only take every other element due to a step being 2. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, try this- can you have it print the entire first row?

Comment: I added the examples above

Comment: Thanks! So looking at the examples that you posted & the changes in your code (assuming I'm getting a better handle on the use case here), do the following:

X_train = array[:,1:-1]
Y_train = array[:,-1]

X_test = testarray[:,1:-1]
Y_test = testarray[:,-1]